# QT Serial send a Byte

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

Is there a way to send a byte to serial with QT.
I only found a function for sending chars.

```
serialport->write(const QByteArray &data)
```

I want to send a array with these three bytes in Hex: 0xF0 0x02 0x0D

Comment: What do you think is the difference between `byte` and `char`? Perhaps the sign? If you have a function that sends some bytes, why can't you use the mechanism to send 1 byte?

Comment: QT is a **C++** toolkit. C is a different language. Don't add unrealted tags.

Comment: I have to send no printable characters to a serial device.

Comment: @WeatherVane:; From the standard actually none. it uses both terms interchangeable. But OP might want to send a type with 8 bits guaranteed, though.

Comment: I want to send the Hex value 0xF0 over the Serialport.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't know that `byte` was standard defined. It is usually `unsigned` whereas the sign for `char` is implementation defined. Pls don't remind me about `CHAR_BIT`.

Comment: @BastiAn please show what you tried. If you can send 2 chars, you can send 1. **Edit:** oops - you now say you are sending 3. So is this a question about *quality* or about *quantity*?

Comment: @WeatherVane: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.7.1 and others The standard happily mixes both terms (see the definition of "alignment" and `alignas`. Not sure if it really explicitly states they are identical, but there definitively is a causal chain.

Comment: @Olaf please be clear. Is `byte` a standard type, or not? "Using the terms interchangeably" is loose.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is not a type, but used synonomyously for "character" and where one would expect the standard type `char` (mind the use of markup).

Answer (score 2):

Do you have something like

```
 serialport->write(QByteArray::fromHex("F0020D"));
```

in mind ?

Answer (score 1):

You send **8-bit values**. "Hexadecimal" is just **a form of notation** of integer values.

```
QByteArray ba;
ba.resize(3);
ba[0] = 0xF0;
ba[1] = 0x02;
ba[2] = 0x0D;
serialport->write(ba);
```

or:

```
char arr[3] = {0xF0, 0x02, 0x0D};
QByteArray ba(arr, 3);
serialport->write(ba);
```